# With Dockerized Cypress test I am getting consistent failure on cy.visit('/); Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms`

Tags: node.js, docker, cypress

Project Details: NodeJs v16.16.0 Cypress v12.8.18

I am setting up Dockerized cypress tests and I am receiving an error from cy.visit('/'). I was able to get these tests working locally but upon pushing the tests out to the server and doing the requisite config changes. I cannot get past cy.visit('/'). I turned on video recording and upon inspection I can see that the page seems to load and make a connection to the desired database, as I can see populated data that is expected and the user icon attached to the account that is supposed to be signing in.
[Cypress Failure Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LseCY.png)
[Cypress spec file]

```
describe("Verify Home page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept(
      `${Cypress.env("SERVER_URL")}/app-api/v1/app`
    ).as("getappinfo");
    cy.seedDb();
    cy.loginAsUser();
    cy.visit("/");
  });

  it("Base page loads successfully", () => {
    cy.get("body").contains("AppName");
  });
});
```

[Cypress Config File]

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  video: false,
  screenshotOnRunFailure:false,
  fixturesFolder: "cypress/fixtures",
  env: {
    VUE_APP_TESTING_TENANT_ID: "####",
    VUE_APP_TESTING_TENANT_CLIENT_ID: "####",
    AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET: "####",
    USER_NAME_ASSOC:
      "testUser01@onmicrosoft.com",
    USER_PASSWORD_ASSOC: "####",
    AUTH_ENVIRONMENT: "login.windows.net",
    SERVER_URL: "https://Appserver.company.domain",
    DIFFERENT_APP_SERVER_URL:'https://DifferentAppServer.company.domain/',
    THIRD_APP_SERVER_URL:'https://ThirdAppServer.company.domain/',
    IS_LOCAL: false
  },
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "https://Appserver.company.domain",
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
```

In this case I am just trying to get past this error as I suspect that after this is remediated all tests will pass being that it is a very simple spec file. Things that I have tried are configuration changes such as adjusting timeouts, adding retries, and adjusting spec files to be as barebones as possible to make sure the issue is indeed with cy.visit('/'). Upon all of these changes there was no difference in my results. Once I had tried all of this I execed into the docker container that is running the tests and added `DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run` to see if I could find anything in the logs that would lead to some clarity.

I looked through the log file and compared it to one that I grabbed from my local environment to see if I could find any differences that would give me a hint as to what the problem is. I was able to find some things including this [log-file reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DajCh.png). I implemented a change that got rid of this error but still the cy.visit('/') fails.

Other things:
-I verified that the baseurl and node_env variable are set correctly and can log them to the console seeing what is expected.
-I monitored the browser and tried to replicate the issue locally seeing if there was some asset tat was trying to reach out externally and wasnt able to thus hanging the app without displaying any visual indicators.
-In the cypress run logs there are several mentions of localhost, I checked the project and the only location that specifies localhost is a development vue.config file. I removed those lines and they still appear so I am not sure where that is coming from and if that could be my issue.
-Lastly, this was previously working about a month ago. I have been in constant contact with the developers on this team and we are trying to find out what exactly changed. If it is an issue with the code base change or if over the course of a month I forgot a change that I need to make.

Comment: Just checked in with Infrastructure team and they are seeing blocks from the spun up container to some of the page elements. Getting that opened up and will post if that was the fix